# Run HHVM and PHP simultaneously with Nginx

Tags: php, magento, nginx, hhvm

I've been running a magento site using HHVM and Nginx. So far I hadn't experienced any problems and all I got was a very welcomed noticeable performance boost.

However, I've just added a plugin which uses PHP functions which are unsupported by HHVM. The good news is that this plugin is only needed for one page. Bad news is I'm not configuring Nginx right to serve this page only with PHP.

The usual fallback trick used by some people using error directives does not work in this case because the page doesn't throw an error. It just doesn't work if HHVM is enabled.

Instead, I've tried to write many variations of location blocks for that particular page. None worked, and these are the two that I had thought would do the trick.

Is there a way to run PHP only for a specific page?

FAILED SOLUTION 1

```
location  ~ /page/.+\.php${

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; ##Unix socket
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;      
}

location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

FAILED SOLUTION 2 (with nested location)

```
location ~ /page/ {

    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; ##Unix socket
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

    }
}

location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using variable condition approach, it works for me, locations starting with `/serve-with-php/` are being served with `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`, while all the others are being served with `127.0.0.1:9000`

```
server {
    root /home/vearutop/test-hhvm;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log error;
    charset        utf-8;

    server_name test-hhvm;

    location / {
        set $fcgi_worker 127.0.0.1:9000; # hhvm handle
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location /serve-with-php/ {
        set $fcgi_worker unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # php-fpm handle
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass $fcgi_worker;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That does the job indeed. My only problem is that my location would ideally need regex and `location /` would always seem to come first before that. Other than that, it works great. I'm also using `fastcgi_keep_conn on;` in the `\php$` location as that seems to be required for HHVM. No conflict so far